# Previous and next month report

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a table where is Date,Time,Place,Text.

Right now it will report current year and month.

I am trying to create 3 buttons which will create report from database.

1. Button will report previous month
2. Button will report actual month
3. Button will report the next month

BUT the problem is when i click the previous or next month it will report only the previous and next month of the current month. So i am looking for some kind of tracking the date.

**Example :**

> March(current) ->(pressed next month button) = April -> (pressed next month button) = May ... etc
>
> March(current)->(pressed prev. month button) = February -> (pressed prev month button) = January
>
> `+ if is pressed next month when is DECEMBER 2013 reported then it must be new YEAR with january`
>
> `+ same condition when backwards (January 2014 ->(previous button) = december 2013)`

Any ideas how to do it ?

```sql
SELECT hlavni.datum_expirace, hlavni.priloha, hlavni.nazev, vedle.misto
FROM hlavni
INNER JOIN vedle ON hlavni.sekce = vedle.idecko WHERE vedle.idecko IN ( 6, 7, 8, 15, 14,
16, 17 ) AND YEAR( datum_expirace ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) AND MONTH(datum_expirace) =
MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) ORDER BY `hlavni`.`datum_expirace` ASC, `hlavni`.`priloha` ASC");
```

Comment: Don't use MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) but pass desired month as parameter to the query.

Comment: I am sorry, i dont understand. I am still new to this thing ^^. Can you give me an explanation what you mean ?

Comment: Do you use by AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below login: you can try with your modification:
You can use it as referrence for you:

```
take one hidden field store in it current date:
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-01'); ?>" />

If you click On any of your three option pass type of it at submit time.
Now when you submit for Next,Previous,Current Month you need to check:

if ($_POST['type'] == 'previous') 
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($_POST['date'])));
} else if ($_POST['type'] == 'next') {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($_POST['date'])));
} else {
    $date = $_POST['date'];
}

 $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 year", strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($date))));
 $end_date = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date));
 $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 second', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($matrix_e_date_no))));


 $loop_start_date = strtotime($start_date);
 $loop_end_date = strtotime($end_date);


 while ($loop_start_date < $loop_end_date) {

 //Print your html content here    
 $loop_start_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', $loop_start_date)));
 }

$set_date_again_in_hidden_field = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: still I cannot get it into a functional state :/

Comment: You just need to concentrate into this code,try to understand, and make necessary changes.

Comment: I am begging you for a hint ^^ i am still kind a new to mysql

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following
assumeing date format is yyyy-mm-dd

for previous month 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(date_created - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

for next month 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(date_created + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)